# How to get javascript result into php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use the search engine of different newspapers sites to get all articles of newspapers which are selected by keyword and then delete  articles that are too much similar.
I'm trying to use http://www.20minutes.fr/search?q=test search engine but as many other search engine the html result is generated by javascript:

```
<script>
          (function() {
            var cx = '011646568010423734157:bmweo2mlsou';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
          })();
        </script>
```

and i cant access the url with curl.
How can i get these url ?
thank you for reading.

Comment: Why would you need HTML at all? Sure, you'd have to know the target URL, the request type and the field names, but from there, you can just directly forge an HTTP(S) request...

Comment: looks like JSONP, just use it the same way they do...?